# Corona sdk enterframe event issue with director

Tags: function, lua, event-handling, coronasdk

I am having problems with getting a scene to change based on event listeners and global variables.

Basically the scene reiterates after certain selections have been made which increments the variable `finalcount`, as the level of choices needs to be limited. The scene should change when the counter reaches 4, which makes the `finalcountscene` variable equal to 1. This should then trigger the change of scene, instead `scenechangeworking` 5 times. So the function works but the scene will not change. Please help! The code can be found below.

```
local function scenechangecount (event)
    if gameState.finalcountscene == 1 then
        Runtime:removeEventListener( "enterFrame",  maincount )
        director:changeScene ("gamemenu")
        print("scene change working")
        Runtime:removeEventListener( "enterFrame",  scenechangecount)
end
end

local function maincount (event)
    if gameState.finalcount == 4 then
        gameState.finalcountscene = 1
     print("working",gameState.finalcount, "scene count", gameState.finalcountscene)
     Runtime:removeEventListener( "enterFrame",  maincount)

    elseif gameState.finalcount == 3 then
       gameState.finalcount = gameState.finalcount +1
       print(gameState.finalcount)
       local message = display.newImage ("images/message.png")
       message.x = display.contentWidth/2 - display.contentWidth/6 
       message.y = display.contentHeight/2 - display.contentHeight/4 - display.contentHeight/18
       localGroup:insert(message)
       Runtime:removeEventListener( "enterFrame",  maincount )

    else
       gameState.finalcount = gameState.finalcount + 1
       print(gameState.finalcount)
       Runtime:removeEventListener( "enterFrame",  maincount )
end
end

Runtime:addEventListener ("enterFrame", scenechangecount)
Runtime:addEventListener ("enterFrame", maincount)
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of issues.  First in your first function scenechangecount, you call director to change scenes before you remove the enterFrame listener so your function is going to continue to run and try to change scenes multiple times.  Try moving the director call to the last of those three lines.

Secondly it seems that you are removing the maincount enter frame every time but at least above you're only adding it once.  So I don't see how your incrementing the counter the way you are removing that enterframe.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the respone. I have changed the order of the call to director to change scenes but it iterates the call numerous times and but does not change scene. The reason I remove the event listener is because the counter is incremented every time the scene is returned to. Its like a menu page where buttons lead to different external scenes and so when this scene is returned to the count increases. If anyone can figure this out I will be eternaly grateful

Comment: What condition should cause gameState.finalcount to increment?  I'm not sure you want to use an enterFrame listener to call maincount().

You setup the enterFrame listener for maincount() and call it, incrementing the gameState.finalcount variable then immediately remove the enterFrame listener.  I don't see how you get back to this function.  Are you setting the enterFrame listener somewhere else?